# Change location settings across all Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

I have created forms in Cognito for several languages and if I have read the location settings help page right the settings only change on the country you register in, not by form.

Am I able to change this?

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/).

We do give users the ability to change the Country, Language, Currency and Time zone at the form level. Once you have entries for a from however the form will be locked into the choices of the time the entry was submitted.

You can make the changes to your form in the Form Settings menu on the left side of the page, to access this menu click on your forms title on the build page.

[image]

Comment: Also, if your form already has a ton of entries, you can Copy your form, which will then allow you to change the location settings.